# Can you color a cell based on another cell's contents in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, conditional-formatting

I have a project I'm working on with reports in MS Word that have similarly structured tables, but some of the cells are different colors depending on the report. To fill them in, I'm using a merge. I know I can format a cell or text based on the cell contents, but what about *adjacent* cells? I would like for cells to be shaded a light blue if the cells next to them have a specific text. Obviously this is easy in Excel, but is it possible in Word?

Comment: Since this is for a mailmerge, see *Conditionally Shade Table Cells* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html